# Setting initial values to dynamic form in antd 4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have a problem while creating dynamic form in antd4, following [this example from docs](https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-dynamic-form-item).

I want to use dynamic form to edit object which already has some values.

In this sandbox I created a new array of initial values: https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-form-item-ant-design-demo-slm8o?file=/index.js:636-649

The goal is to achieve this state when opening form:

[image]

Grateful for any help.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to pass an object to `initialValues` prop, that contains an array of values for `names` field list, like so:

```
    <Form
      name="dynamic_form_item"
      initialValues={{ names: ['', '', ''] }}
      {...formItemLayoutWithOutLabel}
      onFinish={onFinish}
    >
        <Form.List name="names">
            { /* your array of fields goes here */ }
        </Form.List>
    </Form>
```

Comment: Just one thing: initializing it to empty string ('') won't show the placeholder, so I initialized them to [null, null, null]

Answer (score 0):

```
<Form
 form={buildingForm}
 onFinish={onFinishBuildingCreate}
 initialValues={{
  officesInfo: [
   { office_type: "Head Office", employee: 0 },
  ],
}}
>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.